# Employment date off by about two weeks on background check?

Tags: job-offer

Currently going through background check for a new job and ran into a problem.

On my resume I thought one of my previous works started in late May 2015, and May 2015 is what I put on my resume and background check info.

However during the background check it shows the actual start date provided by my previous company shows mid June 2015, so roughly two weeks or so off.
It was about 6 years ago and bad memory on my part (couldn't find the original offer letter from that company that states the date).

Would a small discrepancy like this cause any problems? Should I wait for the whole thing to complete or contact HR right away to explain that I made a mistake on the dates?

Comment: I'm honestly a bit surprised you're even getting feedback on your background check. In the United States, at least, I wouldn't expect companies to share their findings with you..

Comment: @neubert it's not a real feedback feedback, I was just checking the progress on the background check provider's website, and saw that under the employment history section the stated date and verified date is a little different. The provider will also have section satisfaction rating and any findings worthy of noting stated on there once the section is completed.

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/168863/omitted-less-than-2-week-employment-from-5-years-ago-in-background-check-which-w/168864#168864

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't cause any issues to you.  People are aware that memories get bad over time and you're within a couple of weeks - it's not as if you're adding years on.

You could email HR out of courtesy and ask for your information to be updated, but I don't believe this will cause you any significant issues.

Comment: Thank you. I have 3 different jobs listed for the time period they are checking, and the other two more recent jobs returned ok. I think I will wait until the complete other parts of the background check to see if I need to contact them.